# ¿Es "Gerundio" un nombre propio frecuente?

Tags: españa, nombres-propios

Hace años que encontré que, lo que para mi era siempre un apellido, "**García**", en Navarra y Aragón (España) se utilizan también como nombre de pila, y no son excepcionales las personas que lo llevan como nombre de pila y de apellido (García García).

Esto hace que al encontrar el nombre propio "**Gerundio** Zotes" (en la historia de fray Gerundio de Campazas) me haya surgido una duda similar: **Gerundio** ¿es un nombre propio (más o menos) frecuente? ¿En qué zonas?

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [Spanish.SE]! "Gerundio" debe de ser un nombre muy poco frecuente en España, porque [la página del INE que permite buscar nombres propios](http://www.ine.es/dyngs/INEbase/es/operacion.htm?c=Estadistica_C&cid=1254736177009&menu=resultados&idp=1254734710990) dice que en todo el país hay 20 o menos habitantes con ese nombre (vamos, que no da estadísticas).

Comment: La novela es satírica y pretende ridiculizar el lenguaje altisonante y rebuscado que utilizaban algunos clérigos. De ahí el nombre del protagonista, pues el abuso del gerundio es una de las señas de este tipo de lenguaje. Sinceramente, no creo que el padre Isla, autor de la obra, conociera de ninguna persona real con ese nombre. Al igual que el apellido Zotes es otra crítica al personaje.

Answer (score 6):

En la web del INE, como decía en los comentarios, no aparece nadie llamado Gerundio en España. Y en la web de [Family Search](https://familysearch.org), si buscamos solamente en España, tampoco aparece nadie llamado Gerundio (y eso que tienen registros desde el siglo XVI, aunque no de todas las provincias, por lo que hay lagunas).

Sin embargo, si buscamos en todo el mundo, sí que aparece un conjunto de [565 resultados](https://familysearch.org/search/record/results?count=20&query=%2Bgivenname%3AGerundio) de personas llamadas así, y la mayoría son de Filipinas. Puede que el nombre se hiciera popular allí. He comprobado los originales y sí, efectivamente pone "Gerundio" en los nombres.

Si restringimos la búsqueda al siglo XVIII (en el que apareció la novela en la que se menciona a Gerundio Zotes), solo aparecen [2 resultados](https://familysearch.org/search/record/results?count=20&query=%2Bgivenname%3AGerundio%20%2Bbirth_year%3A1700-1800~), ambos de Colombia, y examinando los originales me da que ninguno de los dos resultados es correcto (uno parece ser "Gervasio" y el otro parece "Ovidio" o algo así, no atino a descifrar el nombre, pero "Gerundio" no creo que sea). Así que los resultados de Colombia quedan descartados.

Antes de ese siglo ya no se encuentran resultados. Como conclusión: no, "Gerundio" no es un nombre común en absoluto, y su uso parece quedar restringido principalmente a las Filipinas.